# How to parse an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, parsing

I wanted to parse an input string (path) into the array.

For example, if the input is

> cd("C/Hra/Halo 4/Hra");

The array should contains `{"C","Hra","Halo 4","Hra"}`, but it contains `{"C","Hra","Halo 4,"HraC"}`.
My friend suggested me to put `"\0"` for each string, but it doesn't work.

Can someone please suggest me how to repair it?

My code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
 void cd(char* path){
    printf("Path %s \n",path);
    int count = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int length = (int)strlen(path);
    for(i;i<length;i++){
        if(path[i]=='/')
         count ++;
    }
  char foldersName[count][255];
  char str[strlen(path)];
  strcpy(str,path);
  char * pch;
  pch = strtok (str,"/");
  count = 0;
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    strcpy(foldersName[count],pch);
    strcat(foldersName[count],"\0");
    pch = strtok (NULL, "/");
    count ++;
  }
  printf("----------------Tokens-----------\n");
  for(i =0;i<count;i++){
    printf("%s \n",foldersName[i]);
  }
}

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

   cd("C/Hra/Halo 4/Hra");

}
```

Comment: `char foldersName[count][255];char str[strlen(path)];` --> `char foldersName[count+1][255];char str[length+1];`

Answer (score 1):

`str` doesn't have space for the null byte.

Change

```
   char str[strlen(path)];
```

to

```
   char str[strlen(path)+1];
```

Similarly `char foldersName[count][255];` needs change in size too: `char foldersName[count+1][255];`. With the way, you count `/`, you could endup with a `count` value that's far bigger than the necessary. For example, a path could end with a trailing `/` (`/usr/bin/`), there can be multiple consecutive `/` in a path (`/usr//bin//lib//`) etc. The same could pose a problem when you tokenize the string on `/`.

`strtok()` returns a null byte terminated string. So, you don't need to do: `strcat(foldersName[count],"\0");`.

Your program contains several other minor issues/limitations too:

- use `size_t` for storing the return value of `strlen()`.
- Be aware that `strtok()` modifies its input (that's why you had to make a *copy* of `path`).
- `foldersName[count][255];` allocates a [variable length array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (VLA). If `path` is very long (contains too many `/`) then the allocation could fail which can't be easily detected.
- If any of the path components are longer then 255 you'll have [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow).